# How to restrict input to only whole numbers in Oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, ddl, create-table

I am making a naive ratings platform db and I want to restrict a rating to be whole numbers from 1 to 5. To clarify I do not want to round or truncate, I want it to show a constraint violation if anything except 1,2,3,4,5 is entered.

The data type I'm using is smallint for rating. If I input 2.7, say, it truncates to 2 and proceeds to add the relation instance to the table. Which I don't want. How can I add a constraint to prevent this?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63079959/oracle-constraints-datatype

Comment: you can't with a constraint . smallint is rounding up the value internally. I post in the other question a solution which does the trick

Answer (score 0):

This is what the `CHECK` keyword is for (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp)

If you had a table

```sql
CREATE TABLE Reviews (
     Rating smallint CHECK (Rating IN (1,2,3,4,5)
);
```

Comment: that does not work for smallint, the value is round up, so I could insert 1.1, 1.2, 1.5.

Comment: Oh I see, thats a problem

Comment: I post a solution to this in the other question, which does the trick but it is quite complex